# Springboot microservice package refactoring in all the microservices

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I need to plan for package refactoring in existing microservices. Change need to be done in all the microservices as well as common code. Each microservice is taken care by different teams. Need suggestion to plan it in a way that it should not impact their existing workitems as well as everything should be in a sync. Any suggestion?

eg:

```
current base package structure
com.abc.pqr.xyz
```

change it to

```
com.abc.lmn.xyz
```

Comment: Sorry, but project planning (even for development) is not in the scope of Stack Overflow.